# pgfplots: axis discontinuity moves entire plot to the right

Tags: pgfplots

## Problem

I want to add an axis discontinuity on both my `x` and `y` axes, but doing so (even with just one axis) shifts my entire plot to the right.

## MWE

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% Colour
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

% Graphing and math
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={semithick},
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south east, rotate=-90, yshift=-1.5mm},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    clip mode=individual,
    width=6.8cm,
    anchor={outer north west}
}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Float placement
\usepackage{float}

% Dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

% Don't worry about the janky looking fill, it's just a modified test version. Although, if there was a way to hide it from clipping through the axis discontinuity lines, that would be greatly appreciated!
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
                        title={Before tax},
                        xlabel={\( Q \)},
                        ylabel={\( P \)},
                        ymin=20, ymax=32,
                        xmin=40, xmax=57,
                        domain={0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}},
                        declare function={%
                            supply(\P)=2.05*\P;
                        },
                        axis y discontinuity=crunch  % <--- Problematic for the plot
                    ]
            \addplot[blue, thick, name path=supplycurve] ({supply(x)}, x) node[above right, pos=0.475, xshift=-3pt, yshift=4pt] {\( Q_S \)} node[blue!15!white, below right, pos=0.4075, xshift=3pt, yshift=-3pt, opacity=1, font=\tiny] {PS};

            \node[] (equilibriumpoint) at (axis cs:50,25) {};

            \path[name path=separator] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},25) -- (equilibriumpoint);
            \draw[black, dashed, opacity=0.25] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},25) -| (axis cs:50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});

            \addplot[blue, fill opacity=0.15] fill between[of=separator and supplycurve, soft clip={domain=40:50}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Image(s)

#### Without the axis discontinuity

[image: This plot doesn't explicitly place the axis discontinuity marker, so, it is fine.]

#### With the axis discontinuity

[image: This plot explicitly places the axis discontinuity marker, so, its placement is messed up.]

Comment: Does `pgfplots` have an option to ignore the discontinuity for determining the boudning box? Or to interrupt the picture while that bit's drawn?

Comment: @cfr Not to the best of my knowledge specifically for the interruption, but this prompted me to dig deeper, and I found a style called `trim axis left` that seems to do the job. I'm about to put that as an answer for now.

Comment: Add `trim left={([xshift=-5mm]current axis.south west)}` to the `tikzpicture`, but I don't know how to clip the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several strange things in your plot. The main thing that is causing you problems is `domain={0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}},` combined with using `x` as the y-value in your plot.

When PGFPlot changes the way it calculates the bounding box to include the crunch, it also includes the long linear plot that goes beyond the axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=40, xmax=57,
ymin=20, ymax=32,
axis lines=left,
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
declare function={supply(\P)=2.05*\P;},
]
\addplot[
blue, thick,
domain={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}},
] ({supply(x)}, x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with tight bounding box]

Comment: Thank you! As for why the function's variables were inverted, it's by convention that P is on the vertical axis and Q is on the horizontal axis, but the function supplied takes it as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

After digging through the `pgfplots` documentation, I've discovered the `tikz` style `trim axis left` which seems to do the job.

> `/tikz/trim axis left`
>
> A style with value `trim left=(current axis.south west)`.
>
> The style needs to be provided as argument to `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]`. It expects (at least) one `PGFPLOTS` environment in the picture. The effect is to trim everything which is left of the last axis’ anchor `south west` (i.e. everything left of the left axis boundary).

- *`PGFPLOTS` manual*

## Results

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% Colour
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

% Graphing and math
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
    axis lines=left,
    axis line style={semithick},
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south east, rotate=-90, yshift=-1.5mm},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    clip mode=individual,
    width=6.8cm,
    anchor={outer north west}
}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Float placement
\usepackage{float}

% Dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

% Don't worry about the janky looking fill, it's just a modified test version. Although, if there was a way to hide it from clipping through the axis discontinuity lines, that would be greatly appreciated!
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left]  % <--- This is what did the trick!
        \begin{axis}[
                        title={Before tax},
                        xlabel={\( Q \)},
                        ylabel={\( P \)},
                        ymin=20, ymax=32,
                        xmin=40, xmax=57,
                        domain={0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}},
                        declare function={%
                            supply(\P)=2.05*\P;
                        },
                        axis y discontinuity=crunch
                    ]
            \addplot[blue, thick, name path=supplycurve] ({supply(x)}, x) node[above right, pos=0.475, xshift=-3pt, yshift=4pt] {\( Q_S \)} node[blue!15!white, below right, pos=0.4075, xshift=3pt, yshift=-3pt, opacity=1, font=\tiny] {PS};

            \node[] (equilibriumpoint) at (axis cs:50,25) {};

            \path[name path=separator] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},25) -- (equilibriumpoint);
            \draw[black, dashed, opacity=0.25] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},25) -| (axis cs:50,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});

            \addplot[blue, fill opacity=0.15] fill between[of=separator and supplycurve, soft clip={domain=40:50}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Image

[image: Fixed picture.]

Comment: Ah, you found the same thing ;). It doesn't trim the bottom, though. If you run this in `standalone`, the result is too tall. (Or too deep, maybe.)

Comment: @cfr Yeah, I found the same thing. For now, I'm just putting in `\vspace{-<value>}` :p.